# What are the options for Glass Mapper model attributes?

Tags: glass-mapper

I have looked through the documentation and tutorials on the [Glass Mapper site](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc), but I can't find a list of the different attributes that are available and what they do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- `SitecoreChildrenAttribute` - Maps children of the current item. Expects an `IEnumerable<T>`
- `SitecoreFieldAttribute` - Maps from a field on the current item
- `SitecoreFieldFieldValueAttribute` - Used to populate default values of a field's field
- `SitecoreIdAttribute` - Maps the Sitecore item ID. Expects the property to be a `Sitecore.Data.ID` or `Guid`
- `SitecoreIgnoreAttribute` - Ignores the property and doesn't map anything.
- `SitecoreInfoAttribute` -  Maps from various item properies according to the provided `SitecoreInfoType` parameter which can have the following values:

  - `ContentPath` - The item's content path. The property type must be `System.String`
  - `DisplayName` - The item's display name. The property type must be `System.String`
  - `FullPath` - The item's full path. The property type must be `System.String`
  - `Key` - The item's key. The property type must be `System.String`
  - `ItemUri` - The item's ItemUri . The property type must be `Sitecore.Data.ItemUri`
  - `MediaUrl` - The item's media URL. The property type must be `System.String`
  - `Path` - The item's path. The property type must be `System.String`
  - `TemplateId` - The item's template Id. The property type must be `System.Guid`
  - `TemplateName` - The item's template name. The property type must be `System.String`
  - `Url` - The item's URL. The property type must be `System.String`
  - `Version` - The item's version. The property type must be `System.Int32`
  - `Name` - The item's Name. The property type must be `System.String`
  - `Language` - The items language. The property type must be `Sitecore.Globalization.Language`
  - `BaseTemplateIds` - Gets the Base Template IDs - does not return the template is. The property type must be `IEnumerable<Guid>`
- `SitecoreItemAttribute` - Maps the context item
- `SitecoreLinkedAttribute` - Maps references using the `LinkDatabase`. Expects an `IEnumerable<T>`
- `SitecoreNodeAttribute` - Maps the item specified by the provided Id or Path parameter
- `SitecoreParentAttribute` - Maps the parent of the current item
- `SitecoreQueryAttribute` - Maps the results of a Sitecore Query. Expects an `IEnumerable<T>`. See the [official tutorial](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial7) for details.
- `SitecoreSelfAttribute` - Maps the current model item. Typically used to map a template section to a different model for easier reuse.

Most of this info was found by reading the [source code and comments on Github](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/tree/master/Source)