# How to get Descendants of a Sitecore item using Glass mapper?

Tags: glass-mapper, sitecore-api

Is there any direct approach to get descendants(child items and sub child items) of a Sitecore item in Glassmapper model.

I know **[SitecoreChildren]** can be used in GlassMapper model to get Child items. Is there anything like **[SitecoreChildren]** we can use to get the descendants

Sitecore - Sitecore 8.1 Update 1
Glass Mapper - 4.1.2.67

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no option to get all the descendants with a simple Glass Mapper attribute.

You could use `SitecoreQuery` attribute in theory:

```
[SitecoreQuery(".//*")]
```

I'm not saying that getting all descendants is **always** wrong, but you **really need to be careful when you want to use descendants**. I guess that's the reason why it's not there as one of the Glass attributes.

The whole list of attributes was posted in another question here:

[What are the options for Glass Mapper model attributes?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10229/what-are-the-options-for-glass-mapper-model-attributes)

Comment: Just remark that `Query.MaxItems` setting limits the number of result items in the query. By default it is 260 on Sitecore 8.1.

Comment: Get descendants is a weapon, sometime a nuke.